# Trouble Downloading Data from GAE Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm having issues downloading the deployed datastore down to my local directory.

The documentation seemed pretty straightforward

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Downloading_and_Uploading_All_Data

I'm a bit new to GAE... am I missing something obvious here?

I run the following command

```
appcfg.py download_data --url=http://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=ds_copy
```

I'm not even asked to authenticate,
and this is the output:

```
12:33 PM Downloading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20130507.123333
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
Error 500: --- begin server output ---

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>If the problem persists, please <A HREF="http://code.google.com/appengine/community.html">report</A> your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
--- end server output ---
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured the remote_api to be enabled in your app.yaml ?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to enable the remote api

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

Update your application then run the following commands:

```
appcfg.py download_data -A appName --url=http://appName.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api/ --filename=data.csv
appcfg.py --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api/ --filename=data.csv upload_data <directory>
```

this taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7944641/2954800