# app engine for python on ubuntu import datastore local

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ubuntu

I'm trying to create a local copy of the datastore following the answer on this question [How to create local copy of GAE datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671438/how-to-create-local-copy-of-gae-datastore) . On MAC/Windows it works, but now i'm using Ubuntu and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 5445, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 5436, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2997, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 5092, in __call__
    return method()
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4874, in PerformDownload
    run_fn(args)
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4777, in RunBulkloader
    sys.exit(bulkloader.Run(arg_dict))
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 4405, in Run
    return _PerformBulkload(arg_dict)
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 4145, in _PerformBulkload
    passin = arg_dict['passin']
KeyError: 'passin'
```

I tried using --passin, but there is no such argument to appcfg.py
Any ideas about what could go wrong?

The command I am trying to use is:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --filename=Downloads/data.csv --url=http://localhost:8080/remote_api
```

Comment: which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: The latest one: 1.9.24 - 2015-07-08 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried setting passin = False instead of getting it from arg_dict['passin'] in bulkloader.py and it works.

```
passin = False #arg_dict['passin']
self.passin = False #arg_dict['passin']
```

Answer (score 1):

The recipe you're trying might no longer work with (or may need to be updated for) the more recent versions of the SDK since the plain password based authentication in appcfg.py was dropped. From the [SDK release notes for](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes) for 1.9.24:

> In all the App Engine SDKs, authentication for app deployment is now
>   exclusively through OAuth2. Authentication using an email address and
>   password is no longer supported and the --no_oauth2 flag is no longer
>   available. Note that email address/password authentication will also
>   soon cease to work for older SDK versions.

Comment: But what alternatives do I have? I am talking about my local development environment. I couldn't find a solution in the documentation.

Comment: One alternative would be to really understand exactly how the original solution worked and adapt it to the OAuth2 scheme. Could mean a lot of work. Might not even be possible. The other alternative would rely on someone who already did this work - try to find such solution published. But it might not exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use bulkloader.py instead of appcfg.py, as documented [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12214). In a forthcoming SDK release, `appcfg upload/download_data` will work again, but it will use OAuth2.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to upload data to the local development server. I am using the gcloud 0.9.85 with app-engine SDK 1.9.28.

I start the server with the following command:

```
gcloud preview app run app.yaml --host 0.0.0.0:8080
```

It will start the API server at some random port (e.g. 64578). You can fix the port with `--api-host` anyway.

To upload the data to the local datastore:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --application=dev~APPLICATION_ID --url=http://localhost:API_SERVER_PORT/_ah/remote_api --filename=DB_DOWNLOAD_FROM_APPSPOT
```